# MongoDB match in pipeline with multiple condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have next data:

table1

```
[
  { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5ef3611fc3e39a4891c479d9"), 
      "bid" : ObjectId("db08c671b5174f49886ca8de"), 
  },
  { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5ef30da4c3e39a4891c479d8"), 
      "bid" : ObjectId("db08c671b5174f49886ca8de"), 
  }
]
```

table2:

```
[
  { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5ef3626fc3e39a4891c479da"), 
      "t1_id" : ObjectId("5ef30da4c3e39a4891c479d8"), 
      "bid" : ObjectId("db08c671b5174f49886ca8de")
  }
]
```

I have next SQL query with two conditions on join

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON(t2.bid=table1.bid AND t2.t1_id=table1._id)
```

and try to adapt it to mongoDB.
I came with next query

```
db.getCollection("table1").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "_id" : NumberInt(0), 
                "leads" : "$$ROOT"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "table2", 
                "as" : "t2", 
                "let" : { 
                    "bid" : "$bid", 
                    "t1_id" : "$t1_id"
                }, 
                "pipeline" : [
                    { 
                        "$match" : { 
                            "$expr" : { 
                                "$and" : [
                                    { "$eq" : [ "$table1._id","$$t1_id"]}, 
                                    { "$eq" : [ "$table1.bid","$$bid"]}
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$ps", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }
    ],
);
```

I got next result

```
{ 
    "table1" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ef30da4c3e39a4891c479d8"), 
        "bid" : ObjectId("db08c671b5174f49886ca8de"), 
    }, 
    "t2" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ef3626fc3e39a4891c479da"), 
            "t1_id" : ObjectId("5ef30da4c3e39a4891c479d8"), 
            "bid" : ObjectId("db08c671b5174f49886ca8de")
        }
    ]
},
{ 
    "table1" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ef3611fc3e39a4891c479d9"), 
        "bid" : ObjectId("db08c671b5174f49886ca8de"), 
    }, 
    "t2" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ef3626fc3e39a4891c479da"), 
            "t1_id" : ObjectId("5ef30da4c3e39a4891c479d8"), 
            "bid" : ObjectId("db08c671b5174f49886ca8de")
        }
    ]
}
```

And I can`t understand, why second record from table1 matched with t2, though t2.t1_id != table1._id.

Can you help me find a reason of such results and fix mongo query?

Comment: It seems like you have an incomplete pipeline in your code sample, or the example result is incorrect. Shouldn't it be just `_id` and `bid` at the top level instead of `table1: { _id, bid } `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` parameter of `$lookup` takes an expression from the "local" table (t1), which I assume `$t1_id` doesn't exist

`as` parameter corresponds to the output result field of the lookup, not an alias.

In the pipeline, expressions starting with `$$` are variables declared in the `let` parameter. expressions starting with `$` are expressions from the "foreign" table (t2)

So, to directly translate the `$lookup` pipeline stage from your SQL statement, it should be

```
{
  "$lookup" : { 
    "from" : "table2", 
    "as" : "t2", 
    "let" : { 
      "bid" : "$bid", 
      "t1_id" : "$_id" // should be $_id, as from the SQL you want table1._id, not table1.t1_id
    }, 
    "pipeline" : [
      { 
        "$match" : { 
          "$expr" : { 
            "$and" : [
              { "$eq" : [ "$t1_id", "$$t1_id"] }, // $t1_id is from t2, $$t1_id is from variable in let parameter 
              { "$eq" : [ "$bid", "$$bid"] } // $bid is from t2, $$bid is from variable in let parameter 
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried such variant, but don`t get data from table2 at all.
I also find example here (https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-use-the-lookup-function-in-mongodb-1277#%255C%2524lookup+in+pipeline+and+with+condition+example) ,which use in let fields from collection in field from, but it is not working for me too

Comment: Please include some sample data, the fields in the solution might not match with the actual input of that stage

Comment: I inlcuded sample data to question

Comment: @Ragnar please check the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MYuqnDz-JqV) according to your sample data

Comment: Thanks, I found that problem was because $project in pipeline